# given $f(-x)=-f(x)$ how to prove that $\int_{-a}^{a} f(x)dx =0 $?

Tags: calculus, integration, algebra-precalculus, multivariable-calculus, functions

I think I have an intuitive understanding of why this is true but I can't prove it I just don't know how to relate $F(-a)$ to the information that was given

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
\int_{-a}^af(x)dx&=\int_{-a}^0f(x)dx+\int_0^af(x)dx\\
&=\int_0^af(-x)dx+\int_0^af(x)dx\\
&=0.
\end{align}

Comment: How does a depend on x?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. $a$ and $x$ are just variables.

Answer (score 0):

Hint.

What you want is
$$
\int_{-a}^0f(x)dx+\int_0^af(x)dx=0
$$
Now apply the change of variable $u=-x$ for the first term and use the assumption that $f(-u)=-f(u)$.

---

Alternatively, apply the change of variable $u=-x$ to the integral $\int_{-a}^af(x)dx$ to see what you get.